# Transform rotate not working in Quirks mode

Tags: css, doctype, css-transforms, quirks-mode

I'm working on website that is quirks mode and can't use `<!DOCTYPE html>`.
In my project CSS3 translate image doesn't work in IE10 and 11 but it does work in IE9 for the reasons mentioned above.
Is there a solution to this problem except add `<!DOCTYPE html>`?

Comment: No, there is no solution. What is the reason for using Quirks mode? Quirks mode is not recommended for 21st century webpages, because different browsers have different quirks! So if you explain what the obstacles are for not using standards mode, we can work on getting rid of those obstacles. It's mostly a matter of adding some CSS.

Comment: Old technology has been used on this site . not possible to change them now. I only need work this in ie.

Comment: Which old technology? I'm curious now.

Comment: ActiveXObject , htc files and ... this site should work in oldest ie browser too.

Comment: ActiveX objects have no problem with standards mode as far as I'm aware.. But, ehm, it should work in the oldest IE browser? But it still should use CSS3 translations? I'm not sure you can do that.

Comment: if CSS3 translations work in ie9+ I am satisfied, but previous codes shold work always

Comment: I really think you should provide some code that works in quirks mode, but fails when using standards mode. Without that, any answer would just be groping in the dark.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear: The whole point of quirks mode is to emulate the way IE5 worked.

This includes disabling most of the HTML, CSS and JavaScript features that have been added to the browser since then.

If you are in quirks mode then you do not have those features. There is no work around or solution to this; that is how it is, and that's how quirks mode is intended to work.

If you have to use quirks mode then you also have to accept that your browser's capabilities will be from the 1990's.

Your only options are to work out how to upgrade your software so you can use it in a more modern browser environment, or else ditch the idea of using modern CSS and use whatever techniques where available back in the '90s. Probably a custom ActiveX control or a Flash animation. Pretty ugly, whichever option you go for.

I will also add the obvious point you really need to start thinking about how you're going to upgrade away from quirks mode. The default browser (Edge) that comes with Windows 10 doesn't support quirks mode at all. There will come a point in time when you simply can't avoid upgrading your desktop computers, and at that point, you may find that you simply won't be able to run your quirks mode site. It will be a lot easier if you start working toward dealing with that now than if you leave it and find it hits you in the face later on.